# Visual Studio Giving Compiler Error if I add any code to my Main method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and writing in C#. Something very strange is happening, maybe a bug in Visual Studio?

My Program.cs file below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

namespace SystemAdmin
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new LoginScreen());
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I add a line new line of code inside my main method, for example:

```cs
private int number = 1;
```

I am getting 26 compiler errors and one warning, as below:

[image]

When I remove the new line of code, the errors all disappear. What on earth is going on????

Comment: Try it without `private`

Comment: Okay, that worked. Thanks a lot, that was a really stupid question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting all those errors but you can not declare a variable as private inside the scope of a function.

The variable will automatically be set to private to that function.

Just initialize it as :

```
int number = 1;
```

Comment: Okay, that worked. Thanks a lot, that was a really stupid question!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are declaring `private` it thinks you want to declare a property, which should go directly inside the class (not the method).

Comment: Okay, that worked. Thanks a lot, that was a really stupid question!